# Return e.get() and assign it to a variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying tkinter and I'm doing a simple calculator. For that, I need to return the `e.get()` in a defined function to a variable but it doesn't seem to work.

```
def b_add(number):
    e.insert(END, number)

def addition():
    n = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    return n
    
n1 = addition()

def equal():
    n2 = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, int(n1) + int(n2))
```

And my buttons are like this :

```
b_1 = Button(root, text = "1", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(1))
b_2 = Button(root, text = "2", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(2))
...
b_addition = Button(root, text = "+", padx=39, pady=20, command = addition) 
b_equal = Button(root, text = "=", padx=88, pady=20, command = equal)
```

When pressing the `+` button I want the function to return the value entered and delete it after to enter a new value.

I get a ValueError :

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Can someone help me please ?

Full code :

```
from tkinter import *


n2 = 0
###Gui
root = Tk()
root.title("Super calculator")

###Input
e = Entry(root, width = 35, borderwidth = 5)
e.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 10, pady = 10)

###Functions


       

def b_clear():
    e.delete(0, END)

def b_add(number):
    e.insert(END, number)

def addition():
    n = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    return n
    
n1 = addition()

def equal():
    n2 = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, int(n1) + int(n2))
    


### 10 number buttons
b_1 = Button(root, text = "1", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(1))
b_2 = Button(root, text = "2", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(2))
b_3 = Button(root, text = "3", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(3))
b_4 = Button(root, text = "4", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(4))
b_5 = Button(root, text = "5", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(5))
b_6 = Button(root, text = "6", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(6))
b_7 = Button(root, text = "7", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(7))
b_8 = Button(root, text = "8", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(8))
b_9 = Button(root, text = "9", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(9))
b_0 = Button(root, text = "0", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(0))

b_addition = Button(root, text = "+", padx=39, pady=20, command = addition).grid(row =5, column = 0) 
b_equal = Button(root, text = "=", padx=88, pady=20, command = equal).grid(row =5, column =1, columnspan = 2)
b_clear = Button(root, text = "Clear", padx=79, pady=20, command = b_clear).grid(row =4, column =1, columnspan = 2)

#buttons on screen with grid
b_1.grid(row =3, column=0)
b_2.grid(row =3, column=1)
b_3.grid(row =3, column=2)
b_4.grid(row =2, column=0)
b_5.grid(row =2, column=1)
b_6.grid(row =2, column=2)
b_7.grid(row =1, column=0)
b_8.grid(row =1, column=1)
b_9.grid(row =1, column=2)
b_0.grid(row =4, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem might be because your deleting whats inside of the box before it could be used by someother function, im not sure, which function as its hard without the whole code, and also post the entire error code.

Comment: yes..put the full code...

Comment: @ArunK: no, not "full code". We need a [mcve].

Comment: Almost certainly this means you are calling `addition` before the user has had a chance to enter any data.

Comment: Okey it is here

Answer (score 0):

This line is being called a few milliseconds after you create the entry widget, far before the user has a chance to enter any data:

```
n1 = addition()
```

Because of that, `n` is an empty string. Since you can't convert an empty string to an int, you get the error when you try to use it in `equal`.

Comment: I'm not sure about that because I never call n1 anywhere else, so it would do something like "n1 not defined" and even when I put it in the end before the mainloop it doesn't work. Do I have to assign n1 in a specific place ?
I mean can we even return a e.get() ?

Comment: @Thomas: I never said you "called" `n1`. You are calling `addition()`. and assigning the result to `n1`.

Answer (score 0):

change the code like below

remove 'n1 = addition()' and declare n1 as a global variable and initialize it with n1=0

```
n1=0 
def addition():
    global n1
    n1 = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)

def equal():
    global n1
    n2 = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, int(n1) + int(n2))
```

What was the problem ?

The problem was as Bryan Oakley point-outed  in previous answer n1 will assign the value at first time when the program starts. But at that time Entry was empty, conversion of int with empty is not possible

Always try to write program in minimum number of line, below 5 lines can create
all buttons and its grids

```
def create_buttons(i):
    rows = [4,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1]
    columns = [0,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2]
    return Button(root, text = str(i), padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: b_add(i)).grid(row =rows[i], column=columns[i])
b=[create_buttons(i) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm beginning so I wrote all my buttons one by one but I'll read your code to understand how you did it. 
I wanted to assign to the return variable because I heard that it is not a good habit to do global variables, so I was wondering if it was possible for this kind of code but I'm not seeing any solution for this.

Comment: @Thomas youll have to use `global` eventually somewhere

Comment: Okey I'll use that then, thank you for your help :)